# LogiQL: Find maximum value for predicate

Tags: logiql

I'm keeping track of dates in a LogiQL predicate:

```
compilation_date[c] = d -> compilation(c), datetime(d).
```

I'd like to find out what was the last performed compilation, i.e. what is the `c` for which `d` is the most recent in predicate `compilation_date`.

How would I do that using LogiQL?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
last_compilation_date[]=maxd <-
   agg<<maxd=max(d)>>
      compilation_date[_]=d.
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the argmax is:

```
max_date[]=y,last_compilation[]=x<-
    agg<<y=max(y0),x=max(y0,x0)>>
    compilation_date[x0]=y0.
```

as in this example

```
lbi ttt> addblock <doc>
>   compilation_date[x]=y->datetime(y),int[32](x).
>   max_date[]=y,last_compilation[]=x<-agg<<y=max(y0), x=max(y0,x0)>>compilation_date[x0]=y0.
> </doc>
added block '__block2'
lbi ttt> 
lbi ttt> exec '+compilation_date[2]=datetime:now[].'
lbi ttt> exec '+compilation_date[1]=datetime:add[datetime:now[],1,"days"].'
lbi ttt> print compilation_date
1 2013-12-10 20:03:23
2 2013-12-09 20:03:23
lbi ttt> print max_date
2013-12-10 20:03:23
lbi ttt> print last_compilation
1
lbi ttt>
```